# Is function definition always exported in bash?

Tags: bash

I an learning bash.
In bash manual, I found document about function that says

> Functions may be exported so that subshells automatically
>       have them defined with the `-f` option to the `export` builtin.

In my bash, it exports definition of function contrary to the shell variable. But bash manual uses word, "may be exported". Is function definition always exported in bash or should I do something to guarantee its exportation?

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler : Thank you for editing the question. Could you tell me how to make the yellow block indicating quote above? I tried to find the format in markdown instruction for stackoverflow, but unfortunately, I could not find what and where is it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Functions may be exported ... with the -f option to the export builtin.
> ```

That removes all the fluff. It should be clearer as to what it's trying to say.

And just in case it still isn't...

```
export -f <funcname>
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me clearer instruction. Please let me confirm one thing. When I define a function with function funcname() { ... }. And if I don't export -f <funcname>, is the function always exported automatically or not? Does the behavior depend on environment? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Whether something (a variable or function) is exported or not determines whether it'll be passed on to subprocesses. For shell functions, this only really matters if the subprocess happens to be another shell. Here's an illustration:

```
$ exportedfunc() { echo "This is the exported function"; }
$ export -f exportedfunc
$ nonexportedfunc() { echo "This is the non-exported function"; }
$ bash    # create a subshell to see which functions it inherits
$ PS1='\$\$ '    # set a different prompt so we can tell the subshell ($$) from the parent shell ($)
$$ exportedfunc    # This'll work, because the parent shell exported the function
This is the exported function
$$ nonexportedfunc    # This won't work because this function was not exported to subprocesses
bash: nonexportedfunc: command not found
$$ exit    # back to the parent shell, where both functions are defined
$ exportedfunc
This is the exported function
$ nonexportedfunc
This is the non-exported function
```

I don't know of any shell setting that would cause all functions to be exported automatically. Although if you create a subshell implicitly (e.g. by putting some commands in parentheses), it'll inherit *everything* whether exported or not.